# How to set metadata correctly (how to retrieve it) react native camera

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-camera

I am not sure if I understand the docs properly.
`capture([options]): Promise` allows to set `metadata` like `location`.

However, how do I set the `metadata` correctly?! That way?

```
_takePhoto() {
    const options = { location };
    this.camera.capture({ metadata: options })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log("photodata", data, data.path)
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
}
```

And, how would I read the `location` information out again? When I log `console.log("photo data", data, data.path)` there is no `location` information in it.